# Is it possible to install plugin for Skype and Teams in Outlook 2016?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, skype, microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-teams

I would like to install plugins for Skype and Teams Meetings in Outlook 2016, is it possible and how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Teams plug-in should be automatically installed if you have MS Teams installed with Office 2013/2016/2019 or Office 365.

- If you don't see MS Teams plug-in, close Teams and Outlook, sign-in again to Teams and restart outlook. And this plug-in will not be available if you download Outlook from MS Store.

Or you can customize Skype and other plug-ins by going to File > Options > Navigation pane click Add-Ins > COM add-ins in Manage menu and customize plug-ins in the dialog box.

Comment: I have already looked under the Add-Ins inside Outlook, but no trace of Teams and Skype plugins, but both are installed. Is there any way to force the install of the plugins with reinstall of Skype and Teams?

Comment: Yes, you can give a try with that also you can close Skype, teams and outlook, re-log in to Skype and teams and then configure outlook.

Comment: Unfortunately removing Skype, rebooting, reinstalling Skype and logging in, did not help, still no sign of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Wasif_Hasan says, if you have already installed Skype and Teams Meetings in your computer, you just need to check the add-ins in your Outlook like below and restart your Outlook client, then you could see both these two plugins when your crested meetings in Outlook calendar.
[image]